# Focusing text input in navigation view bounces back to initial view when showing soft keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation

The code below creates a simple `NavigationView` structure with two sub views: `LoggedOutView` with a button that leads to `RegistrationView` with a simple input field. I'm using `GeometryReader` because without directly specifying frame dimensions of many of the used UI elements it would not layout correctly (for example the bottom element in `LoggedOutView` should always stick to the bottom). Also, the views should be in a `ScrollView` for the elastic drag effect but it seems this has no effect on the issue.

The issue is that when navigating to `RegistrationView` and focusing the input field when using the soft keyboard on simulator (or device) the navigation view instantly bounces back to `LoggedOutView` (or rather `ContentView` which automatically goes to `LoggedOutView`). The issue does not happen when not activating the soft keyboard in the simulator so it looks like because of the soft keyboard showing the layout has a conflict which forces the navigation view to go back.

I get no error log in Xcode for the issue and I don't know why this issue occurs but perhaps my `LoggedOutView` is not correctly set up? This for SwiftUI 2, the issue occurs on iOS 14 and 15.

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

enum NavigationViewTarget: String {
    case ContentView
    case LoggedOutView
    case RegistrationView
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var navigationViewTarget: NavigationViewTarget? = .ContentView
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            geo in
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(destination: LoggedOutView(), tag: .LoggedOutView, selection: $navigationViewTarget) { EmptyView() }
                .hidden()
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            .onAppear(perform: onAppear)
        }
    }
    
    private func onAppear() {
        navigationViewTarget = .LoggedOutView
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**LoggedOutView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoggedOutView: View {
    @State private var navigationViewTarget: NavigationViewTarget? = .LoggedOutView
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            geo in

            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 28.0)
                    
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: abs(geo.size.width - 60), height: abs(geo.size.width - 60))
                        .padding(.leading, 30)
                        .padding(.trailing, 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)

                    Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .layoutPriority(-1)
                    
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: RegistrationView(), tag: .RegistrationView, selection: $navigationViewTarget) { EmptyView() }.hidden()

                        Button(action: { navigationViewTarget = .RegistrationView }) {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Register").padding(16)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .frame(height: 45)
                        .background(.red)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                    .frame(width: abs(geo.size.width - 60))
                    .padding(.leading, 30)
                    .padding(.trailing, 30)

                    Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 90)
                        .layoutPriority(-2)

                    VStack {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .frame(width: abs(geo.size.width - 60), height: 50)
                            .padding(.leading, 30)
                            .padding(.trailing, 30)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width)
                    .padding(.bottom, 16)
                }
                .frame(height: abs(geo.size.height - geo.safeAreaInsets.bottom))
                .padding(30)

            }
            .frame(width: geo.size.width)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct LoggedOutView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView
        {
            LoggedOutView()
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

**RegistrationView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct RegistrationView: View {
    @State var email = ""
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            geo in
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Spacer().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 10)

                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(30)
            }
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Registration", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}

struct RegistrationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NavigationView
        {
            RegistrationView()
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix that makes it work but only on iOS 15. Removing Geo reader and the one frame attribute completely from `ContentView` seems to fix the whole issue. I still don't know why it doesn't like it if I set width and height explicitly for `NavigationView` with `.frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height)`.

EDIT: It seems that whenever a geo reader is used and the frame height is set somewhere with geo this issue is bound to occur in navigation view. I ended up removing all geometry readers and rely on window.width and height instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull the NavigationView out of the GeometryReader.

It's right

```swift
var body: some View {
  NavigationView {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      ScrollView {
```

It's don't right

```swift
var body: some View {
  GeometryReader { geometry in
    NavigationView {
      ScrollView {
```